Movie about man who hires killers to kill his family
I saw an American movie almost 8 years ago. I think it was released in the 1990s or at beginning of 2000s. I don't know the actors but the cast is almost all white. 
The movie starts with a man and his girlfriend driving together on the freeway in the mountains in a convertible car during the daytime. The girl was dressed red, they were kissing. The man wanted her to meet his family. She meets his family to celebrate some occasion, the family are rich and live in a big house.
Secretly, the man hired killers to kill his entire family including his brother. His girlfriend didn't know he intended to get rid of his family. After the killers arrived they killed all his family members and she knew that eventually, she was afraid and hides because she knew she will be killed. I don't remember the what happened in the end. 
There are some minor details I don't remember that's why I want to watch it again. 
It may have been released in theater or just a TV movie.

Is this actually the same question as this one? If yes, then you should rather have edited those details into the question and flagged it for reopening (which with those details would probably have been no problem). Just reasking the question with another account is not really the way to go. You might also want to merge your two accounts by following the procedure described in the help center. Also feel free to take a look at the [tour] to get a better grip of how this site works.

“Below Utopia” aka “Body Count" 1997

This could be You're Next. It has the family get-together in a secluded location, and the killers hired by a family member. However, it was released in 2011. 

thanks for helping, but it is not You're Next, it's not horror, it's more crime and old.
